# Is there a KDE plasmoid to monitor logged in users?

Tags: linux, kde, monitoring, kde-4, kde-plasma-workspace

Is there a KDE plasmoid which will display logged in users on a Linux system?

Comment: Have you considered writing one?  It would be pretty easy to modify the basic tutorial python plasmoid to display the results of a `who` command: http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma/Python/GettingStarted

Answer (score 1):

[Fast user switch](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php?content=127462) should work for you. Its main purpose is to provide an easy way of switching between users, but by doing so, it also shows you the logged ones.